# Activiti new forms

Tags: xml, forms, activiti

i wanted to ask some questions that i have. 
First of all, i am trying to create a custom form in activiti. i am studying from  [create new form](http://www.jorambarrez.be/blog/2013/03/13/creating-a-new-form-property-in-activiti/). My project file builder is:
[myProjectBuildFile](https://i.stack.imgur.com/wSHXG.png)

The MonthFormType.class is my custom form. The code inside is:

```
public class MonthFormType extends AbstractFormType{

public static final String TYPE_NAME = "month";
@Override
public String getName() {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    return "integer";
}

@Override
public Object convertFormValueToModelValue(String propertyValue) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    return Integer.valueOf(propertyValue);
}

@Override
public String convertModelValueToFormValue(Object modelValue) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    return modelValue != null ? modelValue.toString() : null;
}

}
```

and activiti.cfg.xml code is :

```
<beans xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans"
   xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
   xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans   
   http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans.xsd">

<bean id="processEngineConfiguration" 
   class="org.activiti.engine.impl.cfg.StandaloneProcessEngineConfiguration">

   <property name="customFormTypes">
        <list>
        <bean class="MonthFormType"/>
        </list>
   </property>
</bean>
</beans>
```

My primary questions are,

1)how we define `<bean class=""/>` ?

2)inside myprocess.bpmn20.xml ("FinancialReportProcess.bpmn20.xml"), what value, type will have `<activity:formProperty type="???">`?

3)when i try to extends the AbstractFormPropertyRenderer i can't import it. Should i import it manually?

Thx for your time and your understanding

Answer (score 2):

1) did not understand this question.

2) type should be one of:

```
"string" (org.activiti.engine.impl.form.StringFormType)
"long" (org.activiti.engine.impl.form.LongFormType)
"enum" (org.activiti.engine.impl.form.EnumFormType)
"date" (org.activiti.engine.impl.form.DateFormType)
"boolean" (org.activiti.engine.impl.form.BooleanFormType)
```

For example, for your case:

```
<activity:formProperty type="string">
```

3) AbstractFormPropertyRenderer: This class is part of the Activiti Explorer code. This JAR is not available in our Maven repo however. So you would have to build the Activiti Explorer webapp project yourself to get it in your local Maven rep.o